# Having problems using C's file I/O in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

I have been using visual studio via Bootcamp and today I decided to try XCode.
However, I was just testing basic I/O in C when the problem occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp,*ofp;
    char name[20];
    int age;
    double height;
    int res;
    ifp=fopen("a.txt","r");
    if(ifp==NULL)
    {
        printf("input file open error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    ofp=fopen("b.txt","w");
    if(ofp==NULL)
    {
        printf("output file open error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        res=fscanf(ifp,"%s  %d  %lf",name,&age,&height);
        if(res==EOF)break;
        fprintf(ofp,"%.1lf %d %s\n",height,age,name);
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know, this works perfectly normal in visual studio.
However, if i try this code in XCode, the result looks like this:

result printed out in b.txt:
[image: result printed out in b.txt]

a.txt's original content looks like this:

```
Lewis 28 182.4
James 53 172.5
Sarah 14 164.3
```

Comment: It looks like your input file is a [Rich Text Format (RTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) file, not a plain-text file. What editor are you using to create the input file `a.txt`? How do you save it?

Comment: Also, please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text, as text, into the question body instead.

Comment: I used the text editor in osx and I changed the file name extension to txt manually after saving it.

Comment: @K.Kim: And then you saved it in RTF format? Better verify the result with `cat b.txt` on the command line. (There is no way your C program could transform a.txt into the shown result.)

Comment: @Some programmer dude I used the "make plain text" option on toolbar and it worked perfectly- thank you so much!

Comment: this outputs as intended as far as I can see when compiling with GCC

Comment: @Toby: it turns out that I unintentionally saved the txt files in rtf format apparently.

Comment: @K.Kim In which case you might like to close this question as it is a programmer error rather than a program error. glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the text editor which was a basic program on mac. In order to save the file as a pure txt file instead of rtf file which causes the problem as the question above, you need to go to the format section on the toolbar and select change to make plain test, or shift+command+T for shortcut.